# Bundle savedInstanceState parcelable object is null=null when killing the app in background

Tags: android, bundle, parcelable, onsaveinstancestate

I'm trying to restore my app after it's been killed in background. It always crashes when trying to access the "config" variable because it's null, even after it's been saved on onSaveInstanceState (it always is, I have tested it in debug mode and the outstate has the object inside its map).

What really confuses me is that this is working perfectly on rotation case. So i think there is nothing wrong with the object construction from parcel. It just doesn't work when I kill the app in background.

When I log savedInstanceState within onCreate after i kill the app in background, Config.BUNDLE returns null=null (no key, no value), but Account.BUNDLE, which is a similar object, is intact.

Also, I've tried to add another String object to the savedInstanceState and it also is saved correctly.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        Config config = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(Config.BUNDLE);
        Config.setInstance(config);
        Account account = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(Account.BUNDLE);
        Account.setInstance(account);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelable(Config.BUNDLE, Config.getInstance());
    outState.putParcelable(Account.BUNDLE, Account.getInstance());
}
```

Comment: `onSaveInstanceState` and `Bundle savedInstanceState` are intended for rotation cases or other, very temporary, destroy/re-create scenarios.  Killing the app in the background would be equivalent to pulling the battery out as far as your app is concerned so none of the lifecycle methods are useful in this scenario.

Comment: i think you need to typecast your bundle params into Config

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that the problem is the Bundle key string.

Config.BUNDLE is a String with the value of "BUNDLE_CONFIG" and the Account.BUNDLE is "BUNDLE_ACCOUNT".

If I change the Config.BUNDLE String to any other value without including "CONFIG" on any part of the String, it works, otherwise it doesn't. I've even cleaned up the project, but the result is the same. I don't understand why.

Example:

```
public final static String BUNDLE = "BUNDLE_CONFIG"; //NOT OK
public final static String BUNDLE = "BUNDLE_SETTINGS_CONFIG"; //NOT OK
public final static String BUNDLE = "BUNDLE_TEST"; //OK
public final static String BUNDLE = "BUNDLE_ANY_OTHER_WORD"; //OK
```

Comment: The value of the key string shouldn't matter (within reason). Maybe you have some stale information keys in the the SharedPreferences? Did you happen to have tried uninstalling and re-installing the APK to get a fresh set of SharedPreferences? Just a thought...